# iOS tableViewCell appearing when it shouldn't?

Tags: ios

I have a app thats pulling from a rails api. I'm getting a problem on the post show page in xcode. I basically pull all the comments related to the post and display them. To make this simple I have 1 comment attached to 1 post in my app and the rest have no comments. The problem I'm getting is that the app shows the same comment on every single post.

I checked the api and it's not returning the comment every time so i'm not sure what's wrong?

Here is my code:

pulling the comments:

```
  GFCredentialStore *credentialStore = [[GFCredentialStore alloc] init];

    NSString *authToken = [credentialStore authToken];
    NSLog(@"%@", authToken);

    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    NSNumber *postId = self.postId;


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s%@%s", kBaseURL, kPostsURL, postId, kCommentsURL];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [GFPostResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
    NSLog(@"%@", manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.comments = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Assigning the comment attributes to cell for row at indexPath: 
(Basically their are two sections the first just 1 cell and is using the post data that I pulled across from another viewController and the other section is all my comments)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0){

        GFPostShowCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"showPostCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        cell.groupNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Group: %@", self.groupName];
        cell.postBodyLabel.text = self.postBody;

        return cell;

    } else {

        GFCommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"commentCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSDictionary *rootObject = self.comments[indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary *comment = rootObject[@"comment"];
        NSDictionary *user = comment[@"user"];

        cell.usernameLabel.text = user[@"username"];
        cell.commentBodyLabel.text = comment[@"body"];

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Lastly a picture showing the comment. The blue comment section is displayed the same on every page. The post works fine. (ignore the comment text it was to test if I was displaying the comment)

[image]

Comment: Did you check that you successfully changed the self.comments array? This seams to be the issue since you don't get an exception either when accessing the self.commets[0] in the cellForRow... method

Comment: @Nils Figured out what you meant and you're right. The first time it sets the array but the next time it's returning the exact same array it's like it's not resetting it. Any Idea how to fix?

Comment: Did you look at what happens in the block of the  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) block? Does it get the 'right' comments array?